# Cannot generate xauth files using Ubuntu on WSL

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Quick clarification: I have X-server running on the Windows machine that hosts the WSL Ubuntu distribution. I can launch GUI programs both locally and remotely. For example, I can lanuch `gvim` from the local WSL, and I can also launch `gvim` when I am an SSH-session.

---

WSL is good for communicating with the remote servers and I have managed to get X-forwarding to work. Yet, I keep getting the following *extra text* when I run `ssh -X user@machine_ip` command. **I wonder if this means that all my GUI sessions are insecure?** I can live with such a message if it does not indicate much potential threat.

```
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
```

I have run the following installer and configuration steps, but failed at the last step:

```
mv ~/.Xauthority ~/old.Xauthority 
sudo apt install ssh xauth xorg -y
touch ~/.Xauthority
xauth generate $DISPLAY .
```

I will  get the following error message

```
xauth: (argv):1:  couldn't query Security extension on display "localhost:0.0"
```

---

I have been reproducing the described problem on three Windows machines (two laptops and one desktop), but have somehow managed to get rid of the "`Warning: No xauth data;`" message on the fourth desktop computer. I have then copied the following from the fourth desktop computer to the rest of the three machines, nothing got improved.

1. Contents of the `~/.Xauthority` file,
2. Added the following to `/etc/ssh/config`:

```
    ForwardAgent no
    ForwardX11 no
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
    XauthLocation /usr/bin/xauth
```

3. Added the following to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
    Protocol 2
    GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
    XAuthLocation /usr/bin/xauth
```

Lastly, I keep getting the following "conversation" with `xauth` program across all buggy Windows machines running WSL (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).

```
User @ machine ➜  ~  xauth                                                   
Using authority file /home/llinfeng/.Xauthority 
xauth> generate $DISPLAY                                                                                  
xauth: (stdin):2:  unable to open display "$DISPLAY".                                                     
xauth> generate $DISPLAY .                                                                            
xauth: (stdin):3:  unable to open display "$DISPLAY".                                                     
xauth> add $DISPLAY .                                                                                     
xauth: (stdin):4:  bad "add" command line                                                                 
xauth>
```

Upon checking the manual for `xauth`, `add` appears to be a valid command somehow.

---

I have tried three WSL distributions and they are all producing the same "`No xauth data`" error message. The three distributions from Microsoft Store include: Ubuntu, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Pengwin (Debian).

---

**Please advise how to get `xauth` command to generate some proper "xauth data".**

Comment: WSL acts as a X client and X server is running in Windows side (e.g. VcXsrv, Xming etc.).

Comment: Indeed, I use WSL as an X client, with X410 as the X server. I am remoting into a Linux machine hosted at home. Among all the Windows machines running WSL + X410, with only one exception, all should get me the `No xauth data` warning message.

Comment: Questions: (1) Did you try `export DISPLAY=localhost:0`? (2) Also `ssh -Y`. (3) Is `xauth` present on the server?

Comment: @harrymc (1) I do have a valid `$DISPLAY` variable setup: all GUI programs started from the remote server get forwarded properly; (2) `ssh -Y` did throw the same error message; (3) on the `server`, `xauth ilst` has printed multiple cookies.

Comment: Try `ForwardAgent yes` in `sshd_config` on the client and `X11UseLocalhost no` in `sshd_config` on the server, recommended in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53003587/windows-subsystem-for-linux-x11-forwarding-through-ssh-connection).

Comment: The server has the `X11UseLocalhost no` entry already and I updated the client's `sshd_config` as mentioned. Yet, I have reboot the WSL service and still get the same error message. It bugs me that `xauth generate` should complain about "Security extension" on the client machine.

Comment: (1) Try instead `X11UseLocalhost yes` on the server. (2) Aren't all these "unable to open display" errors related to there not being an X display on WSL? See [this article](https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2017/02/08/graphical-programs-on-windows-subsystem-on-linux.aspx).

Comment: Opting for `X11UserLocalhost yes` on the server did not help. RE: (2) ==> I think there might be something wrong with the Ubuntu distro on WSL. I should have configured X display on WSL properly, as I can both open gvim from the local WSL and from the remote server. (Yes, the GUI is working over SSH as well. I am mostly concerned about _if it is safe to simply ignore the Warning: No xauth data; ..._.)

Comment: Hello, have you managed to solve this issue (i.e. get rid of this warning message) since your posting here?

Comment: No, it has always been there when I start an SSH session afresh. This is specific to WSL installations. (`Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.` shall appear both for WSL1 and WSL2. Remote GUI programs do render locally, via WSL.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the post and your answer, everything is working right except this
error message.

The message seems to say that "fake authentication data" is sent to the remote
session. I don't see how using that data that can benefit any remote attacker,
so I don't see why it is not safe to simply ignore the warning of "No xauth data".

WSL is not a full implementation of Linux. Many system calls and libraries
were implemented, but many were not.

My personal opinion:
I would say that you can safely take the error message as coming from such
a mis-implemented or not implemented feature and just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install an X Server like Xming for it to work because windows does not have X server.

ssh is just forwarding the remote machine's X Server requests to yours and if you don't have it it throws an error.

after installing Xming enter the following command on WSL shell not in ssh

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

this command has to execute every time you open a new terminal

You can also add it to `~/.bashrc`

if it doesn't work install xterm too 
it installs all X libraries.
on ubuntu

```
sudo apt update;sudo apt install xterm
```

then you can use xauth like normal

you can also disable it using `xauth +`

You must also use ssh's `-Y` flag if you want to use X forwarding.

```
ssh -Y user@host
```

---

if you installed xming and it's not working please ensure DISPLAY variable is set.
this variable shoud be set only on WSL and you can use xauth.

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Comment: I think I got X forwarding working already: I can lanuch `gvim` while in SSH session ([Solved in another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157029/ubuntu-xming-on-windows-wsl-can-open-gui-from-ssh-command-but-not-during-ss/1157129#1157129)).The question comes in two steps: 1. is it safe to ignore such `Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.`; 2. I have checked `xterm` and it has been installed properly. I doubt if there is something wrong with `xauth`?

Comment: in your xauth log it says `(stdin):2:  unable to open display "$DISPLAY".` it means DISPLAY is not set use `export DISPLAY=:0` in your WSL shell NOT IN SSH.

Comment: sorry @llinfeng I can't comment in your post. Can you please add the output of ssh running with `-v` flag?

Comment: here goes the logs as requested: [pointer to what I see with `ssh -v -X remote_server`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zfge4x9jhld2pef/ssh_v_X_no_xauth.txt?dl=0). I am inclined to call it a day and accept the hard fact that Windows Subsystem for Linux is not a full implementation for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

May or may not be relevant to your situation, but I was having trouble with the xauth command because:

- I was mounting a drvfs file system, and using it as my home
- drvfs does not support links -- either hard links or symlinks
- xauth tries to use links

For what it's worth, I worked around this problem by setting by XAUTHORITY environment variable to some path in the wsl ext4 file system.

Ditto .ICEauthority and the ICEAUTHORITY env var.  (Even though the iceauth man page doesn't mention the ICEAUTHORITY env var, it seems to work.)